# Mongoose - Populate from another document's sub Document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that has sub documents :

```
var childSchema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });
var Child = mongoose.model("Child", childSchema);

var parentSchema = new Schema({
  children: [childSchema],
  child: childSchema
});
var Parent = mongoose.model("Parent", parentSchema);
```

and documents that refer to the sub document :

```
var sibling1Schema = new Schema({
  nieces: [{type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Child"}]
});
var Sibling1 = mongoose.model("Sibling1", sibling1Schema);

var sibling2Schema = new Schema({
  preferredNephew: {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Child"}
});
var Sibling2 = mongoose.model("Sibling2", sibling2Schema);
```

The issue I encounter is when I have instances of `sibling1Schema` and `sibling2Schema`, and I try to populate `nieces` or `preferredNephew`, those attributes respectively come back as `null` and `[]`.

The population code is as follow :

```
const sib1Array = await Sibling1.find().populate("nieces");
const sib2Array = await Sibling.find().populate("preferredNephew");
```

I can definitely see the object ids in `sibling1Schema` and `sibling2Schema's` instances are valid references to the objects under parent schema's references.

Is that to be expected and I am missing something or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: if your ids are referring to "parent" schema then change ref for parent schema variable

Comment: the ids are referring to the chiild schema, and that's what I want. Children are generated with their own ids, and those are the ids that are referred to in the sibling records. The populate method just seems not to be working for another document's sub document

Comment: show code of population which you are currently using

Comment: I just edited the question